# Django-like: Invalid block tag: 'like', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm Django noob and trying to implement [Django-likes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-likes/0.1) on my Django 1.6 project. I installed the module through pip (Then moved to my main projcet to modify urls.py import that was deprecated) Then I followed the instructions and added the tags to my template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load userpics_tags %}
{% load likes_inclusion_tags %}

{% block content %}

{% if pic %}
 <img class="pic" src="/static/assets/{{pic}}" />

     {% like pic %}

{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

However I get this error:

```
Invalid block tag: 'like', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'
```

I searced a lot but could not figured out what's wrong so appreciate your help.